# Trouble with making a button with image on it

Tags: html, css

I was recently trying to make few colored buttons with image on them.
What would be the best way of making these buttons? I thought styling a li. My guess would be:
http://jsfiddle.net/qvgtL8j3/

```
<ul id="leftsideul">
<li class="button blog"></li>
<li class="button jobs"></li>
<li class="button support"></li>
<li class="button arabic"></li>
</ul>
```

and:

```
#leftsideul .button{
    width: 99px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: grey;
}

#leftsideul .blog{
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/g9cwJeh.png) no-repeat;
}

#leftsideul ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#leftsideul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

but the problem is that I can't see those images. What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: do not put there no-repeat, this should help (edit: bad idea)

Comment: `no-repeat` is quite possibly necessary, depending on the use of the image

Comment: so answer of j08691 is great @NoviceInDisguise

Answer (score 2):

You're using the background-image property but the shorthand background syntax. Change `background-image` to `background`:

```
#leftsideul .blog{
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/g9cwJeh.png) no-repeat;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qvgtL8j3/1/)**

Comment: I fixed it with using background-image and background-repeat. I can't use background because then I lose a color. Thanks for help!

Comment: True, or you could just move the selector with the background color to come after this rule.

Answer (score 0):

Use background instead of background-image 
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qvgtL8j3/3/)

```
#leftsideul .blog{
 height:32px ; 
   background: url('http://i.imgur.com/g9cwJeh.png') center center no-repeat;
```

}

Comment: I fixed it in another way :). If I used background: I would've lost my background-color.